# axios post succeed but no method triggered in spring-controller

Tags: spring, vue.js, axios

I have tried use axios's get-method, it works, but when I tried to use axios's post-method,  post could be sent, but spring-controller doesn't be triggered and no error reported in front/backend. I will put front- and backend code below.

```
//frontend code, post can be sent to server, So my guess here could be correct
axios({
    method: "post",
    url: 'http://localhost:8082/test',     
    data: {
        email:this.email,
        password: this.password
    }
});
```

```java
//backend controller, can not be triggered by axios's post-method
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void Test(@RequestBody HashMap<String,String> map) {
    System.out.print("kds");
}
```

I also tried backend code like this, but none of them worked.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void Test(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    System.out.print("kds");
}
```

Followed are code which I used for axios's get-method, this works, I don't know whether this could be helpful, so I also place it here.

```
//backend code with get-method, this works.
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test() {
        return "returned data";
    }
```

```
//frontend code with get-method, this works.
axios .get('http://localhost:8082/test').then(response => this.msg = response.data);
```

Comment: I've tested your first method (using `Map`) and it works for me. Using postman or something similar it works?

Comment: Are you getting the "kds" printed on the console, for your POST request ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring csrf protection is on in default, which will redirect post-methode and return with a html-file (but not redirect get-method), that means post-method is intercepted before arriving at Spring-Controller(in this case, Test()).
This is why spring-controller not triggered in my question.

To solve the problem, i should either close csrf-protection in spring like below:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()................
```

or use csrf-token when post at axios side (I did not try this yet).

Last but not least, to @J.F., postman is great, thank you so much.
@Raja, Your question inspired me，thx.